# Cloud foundry API - stop application

Tags: ibm-cloud, postman, cloud-foundry

I Need API to stop the running application, after some search I've found this API

http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/apps/updating_an_app.html

if I want to test it with postman how can I obtain token and where should I put it inside postman ?

**Edit**

i've tried like following with postman

**Put** 
https://[api]/v2/apps/211c82e2-7316-45b6-9ae6-1df4dzz74772/stop

**Header**

```
Authorization : bearer <token>
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I got error:

```
{
    "description": "Unknown request",
    "error_code": "CF-NotFound",
    "code": 10000
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the token you can run `cf oauth-token` from the CLI.

You can use that token in Postman by adding an 'Authorization' HTTP header.

E.g.

```
Authorization: bearer token_you_got_by_running_cf_oauth-token
```

Comment: Another option is to just use `cf curl`.  It doesn't have a pretty gui, but it will take care of sending the token and also refreshing it as needed since the token you get from `cf oauth-token` will expire.

Comment: @DanielMikusa - Please see my edit if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: btw, when I run the app summery api (with token etc) everything is working fine... just the update API give error, any idea what could be missing in the request ?

Comment: When in doubt, run `CF_TRACE=true cf <your-cmd>` to see what API end points need to be called.  In this case, there is no `/v2/apps/211c82e2-7316-45b6-9ae6-1df4dzz74772/stop` end point.  It should be a PUT to `/v2/apps/211c82e2-7316-45b6-9ae6-1df4dzz74772` with a body of `{"state":"STOPPED"}`.